# sequence of monotone measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, monotone-functions

I have a sigma-algebra F on X and  a monotone sequence of measures on F, meaning:
$$ \mu_n(A)\leq \mu_{n+1} (A) \forall A \in F $$
It should hold that $ \mu_1(X) <\infty $
I want to show, that $$\mu=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu_n$$ is a measure on F.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first-principles approach: if $\{A_k\}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets then for any $n$ you have
$$\mu_n \left( \bigcup_k A_k\right) = \sum_k \mu_n(A_k) \le \sum_k \mu(A_k)$$
so now take the limit as $n \to \infty$:
$$\mu \left( \bigcup_k A_k\right) \le \sum_k \mu(A_k).$$
For the other direction again let $\{A_k\}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets and fix an index $m$. Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^m \mu(A_k) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \mu_n(A_k) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^m A_k\right) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right) = \mu \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right).$$
Now let $m \to \infty$ to conclude
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k) \le  \mu \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right).$$

Comment: Thanks Umberto. You didn't need any theorem:)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is easy:
$$\mu(\emptyset)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu_n(\emptyset)=0.$$
Sigma-additivity is a bit more involved. Let $(A_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset F$ be pairwise disjoint and put $A:=\cup_k A_k$.
Now let $f_n:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be $f_n(k)=\mu_n(A_k)$. Then $f_n\leq f_{n+1}$ and therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow}f_n=f$ pointwise and $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$. Furthmore let $P$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Hence applying the monotone covergence to the integral with respect to the counting measure yields
$$\mu(A)\leftarrow\mu_n(A)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_n(A_k) = \int f_n\, dP \rightarrow \int f\, dP = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k). $$

Comment: Can I do that without using integral theorems?

Comment: @ Steven33 You need some kind of theorem, that allows you to switch the limits, i.e.  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu_n(A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu_n(A_k)$. This is typically an application of an integral theorem. So my bet is that you probably can show it without explicitly using such a theorem but you would probably prove this theorem in the process.

Comment: We aren't so far in this subject. I am not allowed to use such theorems. But thank you very much for your elegant proof:)